# Compute operations within subgroups in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table that has multiple subgroups. For example, person A has a total of three visits and person B has a total of two visits. I also have the time of each visit:

```
id      visit     time_of_visit            
A       1         2002-01-15            
A       2         2003-01-15                
A       3         2003-02-15             
B       1         1996-08-09            
B       2         1998-08-09
```

I want to compute how long apart each visit is in terms of years for each person. So I want something like this:

```
id      visit     time_of_visit     difference_in_time         
A       1         2002-01-15        na           
A       2         2003-01-15        1          
A       3         2003-02-15        0.0833         
B       1         1996-08-09        na       
B       2         1998-08-09        2
```

Any ideas how to do this in python pandas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`groupby.diff` on a datetime column will give you

```
df['time_of_visit'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_of_visit'])

df.groupby('id')['time_of_visit'].diff()
Out: 
0        NaT
1   365 days
2    31 days
3        NaT
4   730 days
Name: time_of_visit, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

However, timedeltas cannot give you years as it is not a standard measure. You can always convert by your own rules of course (for example divide by 365).

```
df.groupby('id')['time_of_visit'].diff().dt.days / 365
Out: 
0         NaN
1    1.000000
2    0.084932
3         NaN
4    2.000000
Name: time_of_visit, dtype: float64
```